# How to cut a face into an object

Tags: modeling

I am trying to find a way to cut a face into an object. If I delete the faces it just deletes it, and doesn't cut through the object.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title, everyone here has questions and wants help

Comment: what you want is not clear, are you trying to replicate the object in the first picture?